# ZipEntry get parametric checking

Tags: android, if-statement, parameter-passing

for retrieving items through zip entries I am using this code in cycle (ze is zipEntry):

```
if (ze.getName().equals("poi/" + poi.id + "/pict.jpg")) {
  ...
}
```

Problem is, I have in desired folder 1-6 photographs (with names pict.jpg, pict2.jpg, pict3.jpg,...) and I am asking you how to write some parameter into code above, which could handle my problem. Is it possible to write is as **pict(number 1-6 here accepted only).jpg**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
if (ze.getName().matches("(poi/" + poi.id + "/pict[0-6]{1}.jpg)")) {
  ...
}
```

and make sure your `poi.id` does not contain special character used in regexes.

Comment: It says to me "Invalid Escape Sequence" when using \/